# Issue understanding non-recursive list comprehension concat in haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Hello I'am currently studying for exams and was having issues with an answering topic, as the title state, the goal is to create a non-recursive `concat` function using comprehension lists, looking at the solution it is:

```
concat3 :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat3 xss = [x | xs <- xss, x <-xs]
```

Yet I can not understand why that works, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: List comprehensions are defined in terms of other constructs. Find the translation in e. g. the Haskell98 report and translate your function.

Comment: In other words, read: [Understanding Monads (List)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/List)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

List comprehension arrows `(<-)` can be read as "in", like `[x | xs <- xss, x <- xs]` reads "x for xs in xss and x in xs" which indicates that we're unpacking each list in our list-of-lists to its constituent elements—which is kind of like `concat`.

There are many ways to view this, though.

---

Mechanically, list comprehensions translate to `do` notation

```
do xs <- xss
   x  <- xs
   return x
```

and `do` notation translates to `(>>=)` and `(>>)`

```
xss >>= \xs -> xs >>= \x -> return x
```

and then `(>>=)` itself turns into `concatMap` and `return` to `(\x -> [x])` when we instantiate them on lists.

```
concatMap (\xs -> concatMap (\x -> [x]) xs) xxs
```

and if you think about `concatMap (\x -> [x])` you might see it as passing over a list, taking each element to a singleton list, then concatenating them... which is just a complex way of doing nothing whatsoever.

```
concatMap id xss
```

and from the definition of `concatMap` we have

```
concat (map id xss)
```

and finally just (from the Functor laws! Or common sense)

```
concat xss
```

so it shouldn't be surprising that the function works like `concat` does.

---

What about interpreting the `do` notation as we tend to think semantically when in the "list monad"?

```
do xs <- xss
   x  <- xs
   return x
```

In essence, this can be read as "choose non-deterministically one of the constituent lists from our list-of-lists, then choose non-deterministically one of the elements from that list--collect all possibilities from this procedure" which, again, leads to the idea that we're just concatenating.

---

We could also take a lucky correspondance from the `Control.Monad` function `join`

```
join              :: (Monad m) => m (m a) -> m a  -- this looks `concat`-like!
join x            =  x >>= id
```

If we consider the inner `xs >>= \x -> return x` and then use [eta-conversion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion) we have `xs >>= return` which is just the ["right identity" monad law](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws), helping us to see that

```
xss >>= \xs -> xs >>= \x -> return x
===
xss >>= \xs -> xs >>= return
===
xss >>= \xs -> xs
===
xss >>= id
===
join xss
```

and then we can lookup how to instantiate `join` in the list monad and see `join = concat`.

---

So there are many ways see `concat` as implemented via a list comprehension, depending on how you want to think of list comprehensions. The great part is that these are all equivalent and can build upon one another to form a basis for what the lists and their monad instances really mean.

Comment: Good answer, but I believe it is too advanced to be helpful to the OP.

Comment: Thanks—I'm a little worried that it is impenetrable, but hope that a balance of intuition and calculation will lay the groundwork for the answer. I think yours is an important intuition I left out, so I'm glad you added it.

Comment: Both answer did their job really well, luqui helped me understand how to create them using comprehension lists, and tels helped me understand why it works. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7):

You can picture a list comprehension as a nested loop.  So,

```
[ z | x <- list1, y <- list2 ]
```

means  "for each `x` in `list1`, for each `y` in `list2`, yield `z`", and the resulting list is the collection of all yielded values in order.  Notice that the value to be yielded, `z` here, comes first in the notation.  So if we had:

```
[ (x,y) | x <- [1,2], y <- [3,4,5] ]
```

This says, "for each `x` in `[1,2]`, for each `y` in `[3,4,5]`, yield `(x,y)`", and thus we get:

```
[ (1,3), (1,4), (1,5),   -- when x = 1
  (2,3), (2,4), (2,5) ]  -- when x = 2
```

Equipped with a mnemonic for list comprehensions, we can read your `concat3` definition.

```
concat3 xss = [ x | xs <- xss, x <- xs ]
```

I am going to rename the variables to make it easier to read:

```
concat3 listOfLists = [ x | list <- listOfLists, x <- list ]
```

We can now read this as, "for each `list` in `listOfLists`, for each `x` in `list`, yield `x`".  That is, yield all the elements from the first list, then all the elements from the second list, and so on, which corresponds to concatenating all the lists.

The naming I used is unlikely to be seen in the wild. It is conventional to use "plural" names, ending with `s`, for variables that are meant to denote lists.  Pronounce `xs` as "exes".  Taking the linguistic analogy perhaps too far (but it is still common convention), we "double-pluralize" lists of lists, `xss`.  I usually don't pronounce that, because "exeses" sounds too silly.  So you can see by the name that `xss` is a list of lists, and `xs` is a list, which will you help read dense expressions like these.

Comment: I've always pronounced xss about the same as excesses, ever since my funtional programming lecturer called it that decades ago!